# dynamically changing style of vector layer with a style function

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I've created my vector layers with a style function; they all have unique symbology and text; I want to be able to turn the text on/off with a switch, however using code such as

```
layer.getStyle().getText().setText()
```

does not work as the style returns the code for the style function; anyone has any ideas
below is the style of code

```
var vector = new VectorLayer({
        visible: vl.visible,
        title: vl.title,
        source: vectorSource,
        style: generateStyleFunction(vl, config, legend),
        declutter: false
    });
```

style function

```
return (function styleFunction(feature) {
let layerStyle = new Style({
            image: symbol,
            fill: new Fill({
                color: vl.featureStyle.colour.colour,
            }),
            stroke: new Stroke({
                color: vl.featureStyle.colour.colour,
                width: vl.featureStyle.symbol.width
            }),
             text:  new Text({
                overflow: true,
                offsetY: 15,
                offsetX: 15,
                stroke: new Stroke({
                    color: 'rgb(218, 225, 235)',
                    width: 3
                }),
                text: textFunction(feature)
            })

let textFunction = function (feature) {
            var label = vl.labels.propertyName;
            let labelContent = feature.get(label);
            return labelContent;
        }

}
```

Comment: A styleFunction must return a style such as `return layerStyle;`

Comment: @Mike
this do you know if this will actually store a style object in the vector layer itself when calling it later, because currently my return style is embedded within another function as i had to use parametres from a config as follows
`code
function generateStyleFunction(vl,config, legend) {
    let colour;
    let symbol;
    let feature = feature;


     return (function styleFunction(feature) {
....
 return layerStyle;
    })

    
}
`